# PHP empty() function not work in empty array

Tags: php

I need to check empty input when post form data. I Have this Code :

```
foreach(array_filter($_POST['video']) as $video_url){   
    if (!empty($video_url)) {

    echo 'true';

    }
        else
    {

    echo 'false';

    }
}
```

But this code not work for empty input. I `print_r($_POST['video'])` when send empty input(before foreach code) and see this result:

```
Array ( [0] => )
```

how do check empty input in my case?!

Comment: if ($video_url != "") try this

Comment: @syedmohamed: for not empty work true and show `true` message but for empty input not work and not show any result.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['video']) && $_POST['video'] !="") Out side foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `array_filter` is making the array empty and you can't iterate over an empty array.

You should use:

```
$video = array_filter($_POST['video']);

if (empty($video))
{
  echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
// removes all NULL, FALSE and Empty Strings but leaves 0 (zero) values
$result = array_filter( $array, 'strlen' );
```

Taken from the [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) website.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 if (sizeof($video_url)!=0) {

    echo 'true';

    }
        else
    {

    echo 'false';

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string functions.
Check this out;

```
foreach(array_filter($_POST['video']) as $video_url)
{
    if (strlen(str_replace(' ','',$video_url))==0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```